# Use a Wi-Fi Range Extender with a network switch?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

Most Wi-Fi Range Extenders advert that the embedded Ethernet port allows to connect wired devices, such that the Extender works as a "wireless adapter". E.g.: connect a wired TV to a wireless network with such adapter.

Would it be possible to hook the Wi-Fi Range Extender to a network switch, then connect multiple wired devices to the switch?

Are-there any limitations? E.g. connect a 16-port switch with 15 wired devices.

Random product example: [TP-Link TL-WA850RE](https://www.tp-link.com/en/home-networking/range-extender/tl-wa850re/)

Comment: It will likely depend on the context of your question - if used with a router, it should work like that unless the manual explicitly states it only supports a single ethernet device _(if that's the case, connect the extender and router to the same switch)_

Comment: Well, I think my question is not correctly worded and does not reflect my actual use case. I will try to be more specific! Thanks for your comment

Comment: By the context I meant whether a router is involved - I assumed this was the context as it's the most likely; however, it could also be interpreted as doing so without a router. If no router is involved, it would depend upon whether the extender has a DNS/DHCP server and internet access would not be possible in this scenario

Comment: Ho yes, there is a router involved. Here is a more complete depiction of the scenario, I hope it's more clear for my use case: https://superuser.com/questions/1714834/best-way-to-share-wireless-connection-to-multiple-wired-machines

Comment: This is now a dupe of  [Best way to share wireless connection to multiple wired machines](https://superuser.com/questions/1714834/best-way-to-share-wireless-connection-to-multiple-wired-machines) which at least carries some clarification.